# CellTable keep TextInputCell old value

Tags: validation, gwt, celltable

I use a CellTable with EditTextCell

When the EditTextCell fire the FieldUpdater, I want to do a validation and **set the EditTextCell to the old value** if validation fail. But I cant find how to update the CellTable or the specified row.

Here a piece of code:

```
titleColumn.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<QuestionDto, String>() {

    @Override
    public void update(int index, QuestionDto object, String value) {

           if (!isValid(value)) 
                 // Here I need to set the EditTextCell to the value in my object
           else
                 // It's valid I do the work
       }
});
```

I was looking for something like : `((EditTextCell)titleColumn.getCell(index)).setValue(object.getTitle());`

The other solution is to reset all the CellTable like that:

```
table.setRowData(dataProvider.getList());
```

But it's don't work too.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not very knowledgeable of EditTextCell but for other widgets I would catch the ChangeEvent (is it possible to catch it the cell you're using ?) then call event.stopPropagation() if I don't want the user action to have any effect.